# Packet is too small ffmpeg converting wav to mp3

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, conversion, wav

I continue to get this error when trying to convert a wav file to mp3 using ffmpeg.

This is the command i'm running

```
ffmpeg -i 11_22_40AM.wav  -acodec mp3 11_22_40AM.mp3
```

And this is the error

```
[gsm_ms @ 0x5567d18626c0] Packet is too small
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
```

And all the output caused by command

```
ffmpeg -i 11_22_40AM.wav  -acodec mp3 11_22_40AM.mp3
ffmpeg version 4.2.2-0york0~16.04 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='0york0~16.04' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, wav, from '11_22_40AM.wav':
  Duration: 00:01:08.68, bitrate: 13 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: gsm_ms (1[0][0][0] / 0x0031), 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 13 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (gsm_ms (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, mp3, to '11_22_40AM.mp3':
  Metadata:
    TSSE            : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame), 8000 Hz, mono, s16p
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 libmp3lame
[gsm_ms @ 0x5567d18626c0] Packet is too small
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
size=      67kB time=00:01:08.69 bitrate=   8.0kbits/s speed= 169x    
video:0kB audio:67kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.379184%
```

Comment: Actually using the external decoder still gives the error but the file is actually still converted correctly. So thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message appears to be at the very end of the file. Check to see if it still converted correctly regardless of the message. If not here are some things to try:

- Update to the latest `ffmpeg`. Use a current build from the git master branch. This will always be newer than any release and is the first thing to try when encountering an issue. You can [download](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) it or follow a [compile guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu).
- FFmpeg supports both native and external GSM decoders. Yours was compiled with `--enable-libgsm` so you have access to both. Your file appears to be the Microsoft GSM variant, so if you want to try libgsm instead of the native decoder use:

  ```
  ffmpeg -c:a libgsm_ms -i input.wav output.mp3
  ```

Comment: I can convert the  audio files from the command line now. But when I put the command in a bash script file it won't work even though it's the same command.
here is the command that i'm running from the command line (successfully) and from the bash script (unsuccessfully):
`ffmpeg -i /home/fn/audio/Example\ Folder/6058255.wav -acodec mp3 /home/fn/audio/Example\ Folder/6058255.mp3`

Comment: @MitchellJ Seems to be a completely different issue, so I recommend asking it as a new question. Make sure to show your bash script and any errors.

Comment: Will do thank you.